# How to get table names in capital letters in MySQL 5.6

Tags: database-create, mysql-5.6

I want to create table whose name starts with capital letter in MySQL version 5.6 .
In version 5.0 we can use `lower_case_table_names=0` in my.ini file and restart MySQL it works.

But in 5.6 version I am not able to get it to work.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248735/how-to-force-mysql-to-use-case-sensitive-table-names-in-windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `lower_case_table_names` system variable in `my.ini`. Add this parameter at the bottom of the config file:

```
lower_case_table_names=2
```

There are three options available, `0`, `1`, and `2`.  Read up on what those options do: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Note: There is a big difference between how identifier names are presented to the user through phpMyAdmin, and how identifier matching is done from within an SQL statement.