# mysql export changes all mixed case table names to lower case

Tags: mysql

Hi im having an issue exporting 2 separate databases. basically the tables are stored as TableMembers on the server but when i export using either heidisql or workbench these names are changed to tablemembers.

when i try to import the databases and hook them up to the software it tries to find them and states cannot find TableMembers.

I am aware of https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

I do not want to go the route of changing the ini as i dont understand why software that caters for exports cant keep the integrity of the original namespaces given to tables..

Does anyone have any light to shed on this??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force case sensitive table names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248735/how-to-force-case-sensitive-table-names)

Answer (score 1):

You should rebuild the database with all in lowercase, so you won't have the problem in future exports.

You will need to change the my.ini (or my.cnf), adding `lower_case_table_names=2` in the `[mysqld]` section of the ini file.

Then backup the database, drop the existing database, change the my.ini parameter file, and reimport it.

Comment: Yes this works for when you have just created the table from scratch, but for a database that is already existing on windows when you try to export this it will only do so in lowercase.. so my question is how do i get the mixed case results before mysql reads it and converts it to lower case.

Comment: You will probably have to backup, frop, and recreate the database before it works. More info here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16198/mysql-case-sensitive-table-names-on-linux