# PhpMyAdmin export : reference without uppercase

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, export

First, I'm sorry for my poor English, I'm french.

I use PhpMyAdmin with Xampp in localhost and an other PhpMyAdmin on server

My tables are like Personne, Adresse, Titre.

When I use the export option with server my sql is perfect :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Personne` (
  `idPersonne` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `gsm` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `nom` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `prenom` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `telephone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `idAdresse` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idTitre` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPersonne`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniquePersonne` (`nom`,`prenom`),
  KEY `IDX_F6B8ABB9D3E663E4` (`idAdresse`),
  KEY `IDX_F6B8ABB9E8B304A9` (`idTitre`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=685 ;

ALTER TABLE `Personne`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_F6B8ABB9D3E663E4` FOREIGN KEY (`idAdresse`) REFERENCES `Adresse` (`idAdresse`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_F6B8ABB9E8B304A9` FOREIGN KEY (`idTitre`) REFERENCES `Titre` (`idTitre`) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

By when I use the local export

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Personne` (
  `idPersonne` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `gsm` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `nom` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `prenom` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `telephone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `idAdresse` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idTitre` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=685 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

it's makes lines for primary, unique, normal key and auto_increment :

```
ALTER TABLE `Personne`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idPersonne`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `uniquePersonne` (`nom`,`prenom`), ADD KEY `IDX_F6B8ABB9D3E663E4` (`idAdresse`), ADD KEY `IDX_F6B8ABB9E8B304A9` (`idTitre`);

ALTER TABLE `Personne`
  MODIFY `idPersonne` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=685;
```

And reference don't contain uppercase

```
ALTER TABLE `Personne`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_F6B8ABB9D3E663E4` FOREIGN KEY (`idAdresse`) REFERENCES `adresse` (`idAdresse`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_F6B8ABB9E8B304A9` FOREIGN KEY (`idTitre`) REFERENCES `titre` (`idTitre`) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

How have the same result of server?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I assume that by "local export" you mean "exporting on localhost (XAMPP)". Which phpMyAdmin version do you have on the localhost? on the server?

Comment: server PMA 3.4.10.1deb1 
localhost 4.3.11

Comment: I assume that by XAMPP you mean XAMPP on Windows. If so, does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248735/how-to-force-case-sensitive-table-names

Comment: Yes it's work! 
Before it was lower_case_table_names=0 in my     my.ini 
Now it is lower_case_table_names=2 
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust your lower_case_table_names setting for MySQL to achieve your goal. See [How to force case sensitive table names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248735/how-to-force-case-sensitive-table-names)