# Select fetch one result returning null

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

When I use this statement it does not return results.

```
Result<Record> result = (Result<Record>) jooq
    .select()
    .from("Employees")
    .where(DSL.cast("FirstName", MySQLDataType.BINARY)
       .eq(DSL.cast(firstName, MySQLDataType.BINARY)))
    .fetchOne();
```

I want to select only one Result.

Structure:

```sql
--
-- Table structure for table `Employees`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Employees` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `Age` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

I want to select is Jack and it exists but it returns null.

Example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE FirstName = Jack;
```

Comment: `nul`l means that no record was found - turn on Jooq's logging at DEBUG level and you will see what query is sent. That should help you understand what is going on...

Comment: @Shrekt Would you please add some example data? What is in the table and what is the firstName?

Comment: @Shrekt Have you generated the schema? I think you can try `jooq.select().from("Employees").where(Employees.FirstName.cast(MySQLDataType.BINARY).eq(DSL.cast(firstName, MySQLDataType.BINARY))).fetchOne();`

Comment: Why do you need the cast? Such a simple query should look like `Result<EmoloyeeRecord> result = jooq.selectFrom(Tables.EMPLOYEE).where(Tables.EMPLOYEE.FIRST_NAME.eq(firstName)).fetchOne();`

Comment: can i do it with out the schema? just a select to get it from the database like am trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```java
// Assuming this static import
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

cast("FirstName", MySQLDataType.BINARY)
```

Will generate the following SQL

```sql
-- With a bind variable:
CAST(? AS BINARY)

-- If you're inlining bind variables:
CAST('FirstName' AS BINARY)
```

So, this is not referring to your `` `FirstName` `` column, but to the `'FirstName'` string value. What you really wanted to do is this:

```java
cast(field(name("FirstName")), MySQLDataType.BINARY);
```

Which will generate

```sql
CAST(`FirstName` AS BINARY)
```

#### A general note on case sensitivity

If you're using backticks around table / column names in your DDL, you should always be aware of case sensitivity with your object names also in jOOQ. Ideally, you'll use the [`DSL.name()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#name-java.lang.String...-) method as indicated in my answer to create case sensitive names. This also applies to your `Employees` table, which is added to your SQL statement case insensitively:

```java
from("Employees")       // Generates a "plain SQL", case-insensitive table Employees
```

I recommend you write this instead:

```java
from(name("Employees")) // Generates a case-sensitive table identifier `Employees`
```

The reason why it works is because [MySQL doesn't know case sensitive table names on Windows by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6248735/521799).

#### Manual references

I suggest reading the jOOQ manual sections about "plain SQL" and "identifiers" to help clarify things:

- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql
- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/names