# How to make MySQL colum name case insensitive in Cent OS?

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I am using Cent OS 6.5 and MySQL 5.1.73  and I know database name and table name and also column names are case sensitive in Cent os

Now, I want to make MySQL work as case insensitive in Cent OS.

I have tried the below link its worked for the table name. But i need to case sensitive for the table-column names

[How to force case sensitive table names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248735/how-to-force-case-sensitive-table-names)

Is it possible? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: _Now, I want to make MySQL work as case insensitive in Cent OS._ Why?

Comment: I have many tables in my server. While im fetching the result some of them are case insenstive. some of them are CAPS and some of them are lower case so i need to change the all over. If its to case insenstive that might save lot of time for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends from the type of the table you create.
For strings (CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT), string searches use the collation of the comparison operands.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html

for exemple if the table collation is utf8_general_ci the _CI indicates case insensitive

else the collation utf8_general is case sensitive

you can easily change the collation of your table with an update.

example of a CASE INSENSITIVE TABLE (utf8_general_ci)

```
CREATE TABLE  `test` (
`id` VARCHAR( 32 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL ,
`value1` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

example of a CASE SENSITIVE TABLE (utf8_general)

```
CREATE TABLE  `test` (
`id` VARCHAR( 32 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL ,
`value1` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general
```

Also if you want you can change the default collaction as explained here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-syntax.html

There are default settings for character sets and collations at four levels: server, database, table, and column.

Answer (score 0):

Edit mysql configuration file (my.cnf), add ***lower_case_table_names = 1*** under **[mysqld]**. and restart mysql service it will fix your issue.