# Not able to create Stored Procedure from MySQL Workbench, if the database name using capital letters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, wamp, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create stored procedure using MySQL Workbench but it does not create it, if the database name have capital letters. I am using WAMP on Windows.

MySQL Workbench is saying "Changes applied" but when I am looking at the database even after the refresh DB list, the stored procedure is not available.

It is working fine if i am trying to create the same stored procedure on another database which has lower case letters.

Please help me how can i create the procedure on the database having the capital letters.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248735/how-to-force-case-sensitive-table-names