# Can't set lower_case_table_names in MySQL 8.x on Windows 10

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

In MySQL 8.0.12 running on Windows 10, it seems impossible to set `lower_case_table_names` to 2, so as to achieve the appearance of mixed case DB and table names in Workbench. I realize that under the hood these objects may remain lower case, which is fine. But I want it to look right in Workbench, and I could always achieve this in previous versions of MySQL. When I attempt to do that and restart the service so it takes effect, the service crashes and stops. In the mysql logs I see this:

> Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('2') and data
>   dictionary ('1').
>
> Data Dictionary initialization failed.

This seems to be a common problem for a lot of people.

I read [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90695) that the solution is:

> So `lower_case_table_names` needs to be set together with
>   --initialize.

But I have no idea what that means, or how to set it at startup. I have googled all over and read several forum articles but I can't find clear instructions on how to resolve this.

Comment: I assume you have studied https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html ?

Comment: What exact version of 8.0 are you using?  Are you migrating data from an older version?  Are you accessing the server only through Workbench?

Comment: Rick: Yes, I'm familiar with that article, and I need option "2". When I entered that in the ini file and started the service, it crashed with the errors shown. I updated the version # in the original post. It's a fresh install, not an upgrade.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I figured it out. When installing MySQL Server 8.0.x, you have to check `Show Advanced and Logging Options` ...

[image]

...so that you can get to this screen:

[image]

Then you select *Preserve Given Case*, **which is not the default**. Hey MySQL developers: **This setting should be on the main path, not buried in the optional advanced path.**

> ===============================
>
> Notes added on 9/25/2021:
>
> - This `Preserve Given Case` option can only be selected on first-time installation. You cannot go back and choose it later. Editing the
>   config file will only cause errors. Attempting to upgrade or modify
>   the install results in readonly options for this item.
> - If you already have MySQL installed without this desired option, you'll need to completely uninstall it and reinstall it.
> - As of MySQL 8.0.26, these steps are still valid.
>
> ===============================

Comment: File a bug report at bugs.mysql.com

Comment: It looks like selecting "Advanced" does not always show these options on the page above.

Comment: @Razor_alpha the option to view "Advanced" happens when you check a box during the "Type and Networking" wizard. it's not obvious, but at the bottom of that wizard, there's a checkbox that states "Show Advanced Options and Logging".

Comment: @Napoli Thank you. Yes, even with advanced option I had troubles if the previous installation was not properly removed. Luckily I managed to remove the folders and the registry entries manually.

Comment: The options were disabled for me on 8.0.32 then I tried deleting the C:\ProgramData\Mysql\ folder because it was a reinstall. After another reinstall it worked this time.

Answer (score 8):

8.0.11 changelog:

> It is now prohibited to start the server with a lower_case_table_names setting that is different from the setting used when the server was initialized. The restriction is necessary because collations used by data dictionary table fields are based on the setting defined when the server is initialized, and restarting the server with a different setting would introduce inconsistencies with respect to how identifiers are ordered and compared. (Bug #27309094, Bug #89035)

See also: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89035

By --initialized, it is referring the initial install of 8.0.  How was that done?

Comment: If I need to reinstall it, fine, but how should I install it differently this time? I mainly just allowed all the defaults and I don't remember it asking me about casing of objects. Also, I've never heard the term "initialized" as being equivalent to "software installed". Wouldn't initialized imply "on startup" rather than "on installation"?

Comment: @HerrimanCoder - I don't know.  Dig through the initialization script.

Comment: What is the "initialization script", and where is it? I need a little more info, please. I have read the bug report referenced above, it didn't help much.